# While inserting multiple rows what does the statement 'select 1 from dual' do?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, multiple-insert

While inserting multiple rows into a table using the following style :

```
insert all

into ghazal_current (GhazalName,Rating) values('Ajab Apna Haal Hota Jo Visaal-e-Yaar Hota',5)
into ghazal_current (GhazalName,Rating) values('Apne Hothon Par Sajana Chahta Hun',4)
into ghazal_current (GhazalName,Rating) values('Shaam Se Aankh Mein Nami Si Hai',4)
into ghazal_current (GhazalName,Rating) values('Tumhe Yaad Ho Ke Na Yaad Ho',3)

select 1 from dual;
```

What does the statement `select 1 from dual` mean ? What is it here for ?

Comment: Nothing else than select 1, as the statement states.

Comment: Useful question, and brilliant choice of ghazals :)

Answer (score 15):

DUAL is a built-in table, useful because it is guaranteed to [return only one row](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036).  This means `DUAL` may be used to get pseudo-columns such as `user` or `sysdate`, the results of calculations and the like.  The owner of DUAL is `SYS` but it can be accessed by every user. DUAL is well-covered in the documentation.  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/datadict.htm#CNCPT1219).

In your case, `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;` will simply returns `1`.  You need it because the INSERT ALL syntax demands a SELECT clause but you are not querying the input values from a table.

Comment: Dual is not a temporary table.

Comment: That article describes it as *special*.  That is not the same as temporary.  It is a permanent table.

Answer (score 5):

### Brief re-introduction to one-row tables

Some SQL databases require all values to come *FROM* a table or table-like object, whereas others permit queries to construct values *ex nihilo*:

```
-- MySQL, sqlite, PostgreSQL, HSQLdb, and many others permit
-- a "naked" select:
SELECT 1;

-- Others *require* a FROM target, like Oracle.
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

-- ...and Firebird/Interbase:
SELECT 1 FROM RDB$DATABASE;

-- ...and DB2:
SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Here the cardinality of DUAL is important.  If it had more than one row, your result set would have more than one row.  What happens, for example, when you `SELECT 1 FROM A_Table_With_Ten_Rows`?

### Why DUAL is used here

The SQL construct *`VALUES (<row-value-expression>)`* is a row value constructor.  `VALUES (1, 2, 3)` "creates" a row of values just as `SELECT 1, 2, 3` does.

Oracle, of course, requires that these values come *FROM* somewhere.

As a demonstration, instead of SELECTing from DUAL at the end of the INSERT ALL, try a table with *N* rows, and you'll see that each `VALUES()` row is inserted *N* times.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM dual;` can be used in MySQL, too. Postgres has also: `VALUES (1);` (yes, no `FROM`!) and this works in Postgres and SQL-Server: `SELECT y FROM (VALUES (1)) AS x (y);` Oh, `SELECT 1` works in SQL-Server as well.

Comment: @ypercube, yes.  The point is that ora _requires_ the FROM for SELECT and VALUES, whereas my/pg/h/lite/etc. do not require it, even though they may permit it.  I'll clarify in answer.

Comment: My point (which I didn't make it clear) was that Postgres allows a syntax even without a `SELECT` !

Comment: @ypercube, yes, that (a naked VALUES) is a cool feature.  (pg does so many things right!)

Answer (score -1):

There are some samples about using dual in Queries:

```
   select sysdate from dual  /--it returns date of system
    SELECT chr(223) FROM dual /--it returns character of Asciهi code
    select  my_sequence.nextval from dual; /-- It returns the next value of a sequence
    select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd','nls_calendar=persian')from dual 
    /--returns persian date of system
```